# Ubuntu server boot without keyboard/monitor

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

Hope someone can help me with this unusual problem. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 server on a Gigabyte GA-H61M-USB3 motherboard. This all went well. I subsequently installed Apache, MySQL and PHP. This also went well. I am using the UFW kernal firewall instead of the recommended Shorewall (could not find the repository during installation). I thought I had a working server until I relocated the box and attempted to log in using PuTTY. Turns out that the server does not boot without a monitor and keyboard connected. I don't believe there is anything in the motherboard that is preventing the boot. Has anyone else seen this behavior and what was your fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the system does not boot? For example add something like

```
    date>>/iamalive
```

to /etc/rc.local and check that file after reboot.

Are you using the correct IP to connect via Putty (static vs dhcp configuration)?

Comment: Yes, it is not fully booting. I don't know how far into the boot process it is getting to before it fails. I can try your suggestion to be sure. When I reconnect the monitor and keyboard it works fine. I am using a static IP in the server. PuTTY works fine when attached to the monitor and keyboard through a KVM switch.